# Is there a way to have zenity windows not exit after sending an option?

Tags: bash, zenity

I have a bash script with zenity that I recently started running as root.

When ran as the normal user i didn't bother trying to make the window stay, so with every selected option i just put a `"$0" &` before the command, and the zenity window will always reopen.

But now when ran as root, the window wil never reopen, no matter what i try. Including a carousel like "sh -c sudo bash $0" still not working.

The script is this. It is executed with "kdesu -c sudo" in a shortcut to get root. And yes it had many dirty hacks in it :)

```
#!/bin/bash

#runs by default as root

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

user=$(who | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}')

h=$(realpath /home/$user)

width=$(xrandr | fgrep '*' | awk '{print $1}' | awk -Fx '{print $1}')

s1="--width=$(($width/2)) --height=$(($width/2))"

s="--width=$(($width/3)) --height=$(($width/3))"

dt=$(date '+%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S')

files="$h/.local $h/.config $h/.ipfs $h/.Osmos $h/.MuWire $h/Documents/Notes $h/Documents/Programs $h/Pictures $h/.asoundrc $h/.ssr/settings.conf /tmp/packages.txt /root/.config/bleachbit /root/.stereo_tool.rc /etc/pulse /etc/modules-load.d /etc/default/grub"

selection=$(zenity --list "System - Rerun IPSets & Hosts" "System - Reset IPSets & Hosts" "System - Mount ISO" "Hardware - Zenmonitor" "Hardware - AMDGPU Monitor" "Hardware - IO Monitor" "Hardware - SMART SSD" "Hardware - SMART HDD" "Hardware - Turn off HDD" "Memory - Enable Swap" "Memory - Free up cached memory" "Memory - Disable swap" "CPU - Set PState 4.0 GHz" "CPU - Set PState 3.8 GHz" "CPU - Set PState 3.6 GHz" "CPU - Set PState 3.3 GHz" "CPU - Set PState 2.9 GHz" "CPU - Set PState 1.7 GHz" "Diagnostics - RAM Info" "Diagnostics - Run Memtester" "Maintenance - Backup home dir using tar/pigz (fast)" "Maintenance - Backup home dir using tar/lrzip (best compression)" "Maintenance - Backup home dir using 7z (old, more compatible)" "Misc - PcManFM (root)" "Misc - Hardware Info (root)" "Misc - Bleachbit" "Misc - Bleachbit (root)" "Misc - Restart pulseaudio" "Misc - Turn off display" --column="Sort" --text="Choose desired option:" --title="System Utilities" $s)

if test "$selection" = "System - Rerun IPSets & Hosts"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && bash "$DIR/IPsets & Hosts.sh" | zenity --text-info $s

elif test "$selection" = "System - Reset IPSets & Hosts"
then
"$0" & iptables -F & ip6tables -F && ipset flush && ipset destroy ipmaster && ipset destroy ipmaster6 & rm -f /etc/hosts && systemctl restart nscd.service

elif test "$selection" = "System - Mount ISO"
then
if test -d /mnt/iso
then
:
else
mkdir /mnt/iso
fi
if ls -1qA /mnt/iso | grep -q .
then
! umount /mnt/iso
else
:
fi
user=$(who | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}')
file=$(zenity --file-selection --title="Select ISO File")
if test -z "$file"
then
exit
else
mount -o loop ${file} /mnt/iso
fi

elif test "$selection" = "Hardware - Zenmonitor"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && zenmonitor

elif test "$selection" = "Hardware - AMDGPU Monitor"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && konsole --nofork -e watch -t head -n 15 /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/amdgpu_pm_info

elif test "$selection" = "Hardware - IO Monitor"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && konsole --nofork -e iotop

elif test "$selection" = "Hardware - SMART SSD"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && smartctl -a /dev/nvme0 | zenity --text-info $s1

elif test "$selection" = "Hardware - SMART HDD"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && smartctl -a /dev/sda | zenity --text-info $s1

elif test "$selection" = "Hardware - Turn off HDD"
then
"$0" & umount /dev/sda1 && udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sda

elif test "$selection" = "Memory - Enable Swap"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && fallocate -l $(zenity --scale --value="2" --min-value="2" --max-value="16" --text='Choose Swap size in GB' --title='Swap')G ~/.swapfile && chmod 600 ~/.swapfile && mkswap ~/.swapfile && swapon ~/.swapfile

elif test "$selection" = "Memory - Free up cached memory"
then
"$0" & sync && su -c "sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3"

elif test "$selection" = "Memory - Disable swap"
then
"$0" & swapoff ~/.swapfile && chmod 777 ~/.swapfile && rm -f ~/.swapfile

elif test "$selection" = "CPU - Set PState 4.0 GHz" #1.306
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && $DIR/zenstates.py -p0 --enable -f a0 -d 8 -v 27 | zenity --text-info $s

elif test "$selection" = "CPU - Set PState 3.8 GHz" #1.17
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && $DIR/zenstates.py -p0 --enable -f 98 -d 8 -v 3d | zenity --text-info $s

elif test "$selection" = "CPU - Set PState 3.6 GHz" #1.09
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && $DIR/zenstates.py -p0 --enable -f 90 -d 8 -v 49 | zenity --text-info $s

elif test "$selection" = "CPU - Set PState 3.3 GHz" #1
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && $DIR/zenstates.py -p0 --enable -f 84 -d 8 -v 58 | zenity --text-info $s

elif test "$selection" = "CPU - Set PState 2.9 GHz" #0.9
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && $DIR/zenstates.py -p0 --enable -f 74 -d 8 -v 68 | zenity --text-info $s

elif test "$selection" = "CPU - Set PState 1.7 GHz" #0.65
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && $DIR/zenstates.py -p0 --enable -f 44 -d 8 -v 90 | zenity --text-info $s

elif test "$selection" = "Diagnostics - RAM Info"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && dmidecode --type 17 | zenity --text-info $s1

elif test "$selection" = "Diagnostics - Run Memtester"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && konsole --nofork -e memtester $(zenity --scale --value="8" --min-value="2" --max-value="14" --text='Choose Memory test size in GB' --title='Memtester')G

elif test "$selection" = "Maintenance - Backup home dir using tar/pigz (fast)"
then
"$0" & pacman -Qe | tee /tmp/packages.txt && tar -I "pigz -9 -p 16 -v -f" -cf $(zenity --list "/mnt/HDD1/Backups/" "/mnt/veracrypt1/" --column="Sort" --text="Choose desired option:" --title="Backup path" $s)home-${dt}.tar.gz $files && rm /tmp/packages.txt

elif test "$selection" = "Maintenance - Backup home dir using tar/lrzip (best compression)"
then
"$0" & pacman -Qe | tee /tmp/packages.txt && tar -I "lrzip -v -L 6 -p 16 -N 0" -cf $(zenity --list "/mnt/HDD1/Backups/" "/mnt/veracrypt1/" --column="Sort" --text="Choose desired option:" --title="Backup path" $s)home-${dt}.tar.lrz $files && rm /tmp/packages.txt

elif test "$selection" = "Maintenance - Backup home dir using 7z (old, more compatible)"
then
"$0" & pacman -Qe | tee /tmp/packages.txt && 7z a $(zenity --list "/mnt/HDD1/Backups/" "/mnt/veracrypt1/" --column="Sort" --text="Choose desired option:" --title="Backup path" $s)home-${dt}.7z $files && rm /tmp/packages.txt

elif test "$selection" = "Misc - PcManFM (root)"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && pcmanfm

elif test "$selection" = "Misc - Hardware Info (root)"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && hardinfo

elif test "$selection" = "Misc - Bleachbit"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && /bin/su -s /bin/bash -c 'bleachbit' $user

elif test "$selection" = "Misc - Bleachbit (root)"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && bleachbit

elif test "$selection" = "Misc - Restart pulseaudio"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && /bin/su -s /bin/bash -c 'pulseaudio -k' $user

elif test "$selection" = "Misc - Turn off display"
then
"$0" & sleep 0.5s && xset dpms force off

fi

exit
```

Are there any workarounds to this, or an alternative to zenity that is as easy to use as this?

What to use instead of zenity? A quick Qt program?

Comment: Read about `DISPLAY` environment variable and `xhost` man page.

Comment: Call your script with ``bash -vx`` and see what happens when it tries to call itself with ``"$0" &``. By the way, I don't know how long your script is supposed to stay alive, but creating a neverending chain of processes that call themselves like this is certainly not the best idea.

Comment: @xhienne Hmm, never knew of bash -vx. The output is like this: Ignoring the zenity errors it appears to go to the exit command at the end too quickly and ending the script before the if statements. https://pastebin.com/JGmnu7Ev . I have the "exit" at the end, to prevent exactly that multiple process loop you explained.

Comment: There is no processing of zenity errors in your code. Add an `else` statement to your long `elif` chain.

Comment: Your question may be misleading. You state that "when ran as root, the window will never *reopen*" but judging by your output in pastebin, the zenity window doesn't seem to open even once.

Comment: @xhienne It works now with an else : after the elif chain. Thank you

Comment: Yeah i cut a bit from that log showing the window first opening because it had some private info. 2 windows of zenity were spawned with a different pid because some of the options there showed their outputs in another zenity window. Basically overcomplicating a bit

Comment: A weird fix though. The lack of an else statement was causing the call-itself chain to break?

Comment: @xhienne BTW to avoid any problems in the future, is there a goto like feature in bash? So that I wil avoid having the script call itself

Comment: Actually, I reacted too quickly. Your script calls itself in the background. That means that the parent script is doing what you selected in your zenity GUI while its child is spawning a new window. Most often, the parent script ends within the next second. To answer your question: there is no `goto` in bash. You might use a `while` loop, which means you have to exec your actions in the background: i.e. change ``"$0" & action`` to ``action &``. Complex actions may be put inside parenthesis ``(action1; action2) &`` or better inside functions that you would call in the background (with &)

Comment: @xhienne Thank you. Now how do I integrate the while statements? I basically need the first while statement to be right beofre the "selection" variable where the big zenity GUI list opens. And then, after each if/elif where commands get executed, it will need to go back to the "selection" variable, to update the selection by opening the zenity window again and choosing the new option, then running the if/elifs again. This will be the alternative to the script calling itself, but I need a bit of help. I'd be really thankful.

Comment: This is really far outside the perimeter of this stackoverflow question. You should shorten your script to a couple of actions (i.e. a minimal reproducible example), try something and ask for some help through another question. Once this works, you can expand again your code to include the other actions. There is no urgency to turn your script into a while loop; if you are happy with it, then let it be. This is just a weird way of doing things

Comment: @xhienne Yeah it is indeed a bit weird, that was the word :) i will do just that, ask in a different thread with a simplified example. Have a good day sir!